# GCM :Multiple Application ID in Server side

Tags: android

On server side, i found for one device there multiple registration IDs, which obviously is creating for me lots of issues. like messages received many times.

How could I get red of old registration IDs, or make sure that registration doesn't happen if there a valid registration ID.

I follow the example tutorial on Android doc when I wrote my app as below:

```
checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL");
        checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        // NOT required any more GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        /**
         * this code to register reciver moved to message actvity
         */
        //registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
        //      DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));


        /* final String */regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        /**
         * save regId in pref to be used by Location update service
         */
        SavePreferences("regId", regId);

        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Automatically registers application on startup.
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                ;;
                // Skips registration.
                // -- mDisplay.append(getString(R.string.already_registered) +
                // "\n");
            //  System.out.println(getString(R.string.already_registered)
                //      + "\n");

            } else {
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        boolean registered = ServerUtilities.register(context,
                                regId);
                        // At this point all attempts to register with the app
                        // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
                        // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                        // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
                        // unregistered callback upon completion, but
                        // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                        if (!registered) {
                            GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Notice, I could receive messages on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a time ,there is only one registration id for single device, multiple ids wont be possible.

when ever you firstly run your application you will get registration id and that you have to register it to GCM registrar.Otherwise message wont be delivered to your device.

on server side, you need to keep this registration id safely so that you can use it when you want to send message.

your problem of keeping track of registration id for particular device: When you got registration id for your device then save it in your server database if you are using otherwise keep it array.and whenever new registration id is generated ,delete the previous one and add new entry into your database.

Comment: Thanks ... the trick here how do I need there is a new ID is generated for same device so that I could delete old one?

Comment: sry ..
when a new id is generated you will try to register it GCM registrar.

when this new registration id successfully register your onRegister() method of service will be called .checked following code.
here you can add code to replace previous one with new one.


@Override

 protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {


  ServiceUtilities.register(context, registrationId);

 }

Comment: sry but i cant properly indent above code in comment part, cant add this code as another as,its against stackoverflow rule.
from next time please ask new question as separate question

Comment: I created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031167/multiple-application-id-in-server-side-in-gcm