# Multiple Application ID in Server side in GCM

Tags: android

On server side, i found for one device there multiple registration IDs, which obviously is creating for me lots of issues. like messages received many times.

How could I get red of old registration IDs, or make sure that registration doesn't happen if there a valid registration ID.

I follow the example tutorial on Android doc when I wrote my app as below:

```
 checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL");
            checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
            // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
            // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
            // NOT required any more GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

            /**
             * this code to register reciver moved to message actvity
             */
            //registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            //      DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));


            /* final String */regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

            /**
             * save regId in pref to be used by Location update service
             */
            SavePreferences("regId", regId);

            if (regId.equals("")) {
                // Automatically registers application on startup.
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
                if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                    ;;
                    // Skips registration.
                    // -- mDisplay.append(getString(R.string.already_registered) +
                    // "\n");
                //  System.out.println(getString(R.string.already_registered)
                    //      + "\n");

                } else {
                    // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                    // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                    // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                    final Context context = this;
                    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            boolean registered = ServerUtilities.register(context,
                                    regId);
                            // At this point all attempts to register with the app
                            // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
                            // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                            // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
                            // unregistered callback upon completion, but
                            // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                            if (!registered) {
                                GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            mRegisterTask = null;
                        }

                    };
                    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Please refer link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030233/gcm-multiple-application-id-in-server-side/15030465#comment21123039_15030465

Also check canonical registration ids concept :http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

or 

when a new id is generated you will try to register it GCM registrar. when this new registration id successfully register your onRegister() method of service will be called . 

here you can add code to replace previous one with new one.but for this along with registration id you need to send some unique reference to server,so for next time you can check this unique reference and replace existing registration id with new one 

checked following code:

@Override 

protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) { 

ServiceUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
//call service and replace id 
}
```